# Matching keywords of one data frame with other in R

Tags: r

I have a two data frame named "train" which has the keyword to lookup in "test" which has multiple instances of "train" keywords in different rows. I want for each keyword in "train" the corresponding row as well the the value stored in that row of "test".
I used grep to extract the data, but i am unable to loop it for each keyword of train
sample code : `test[grep(("pharma"),test$org_name),]`
this would return the instances of "pharma" in test. can you help me in looping for all keywords of "train" and not just pharma.

Test data :

[image: Test DATA]

Train data :

[image]

Train:

```
dput(train)
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 22L, 29L, 32L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 42L, 46L, 57L, 58L, 54L, 55L, 9L, 59L, 16L, 
41L, 33L, 17L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 2L, 
36L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L), .Label = c("3b", 
"3m", "acadia", "advanced", "ajanta", "alexion", "als", "altana", 
"astellas", "aurobindo", "avella", "axcan", "bayer", "beximco", 
"bluepharma", "chugai", "dainippon", "diffusion", "ego", "elder", 
"endo", "eusa", "ferring", "getz", "glenmark", "gulf", "hikma", 
"incepta", "index", "intas", "janssen", "jhp", "mitsubishi", 
"navidea biopharmaceuticals", "newbridge", "novabay", "nymox", 
"octapharma", "orion", "ortho-mcneil", "otsuka", "pamlico", "par", 
"pharma", "pharmacosmos", "pharmaxis", "purdue", "regeneron", 
"respa", "salix", "sigma", "square", "sun", "takeda", "teva", 
"torrent", "tragara", "tribute", "valeant", "veloxis", "vertex", 
"vion", "wallace", "zandu"), class = "factor")), .Names = "name", row.names = c(NA, 
-69L), class = "data.frame")
```

Test:

```
dput(head(test,100))
structure(list(org_name = c("reassign to novo nordisk pharma ltd.", 
"acadia pharmaceuticals as", "pharma medica research", "institute of pharmaco economics", 
"ucb pharma s.a.", "charles university - faculty of pharmacy", 
"pharmasotique", "laboratoires hra pharma", "jacomm pharma aktiebolaget", 
"wyeth-lederle pharma gmbh", "cyathus exquirere pharmaforschungsgmbh", 
"unison pharmaceuticals", "pharmacetical compaany", "octapharma ag", 
"otsuka pharmaceuticals ltd", "genus pharmaceuticals ltd", "dabur dabur pharma", 
"ftip002859996 pharmalink consulting ltd", "pharmaqualityeuropesrl", 
"smemlt2013022073965_complete solutions pharmacy gen merchan", 
"2-8560138_astrazeneca pharmaceuticals phils. in", "2-4772798_qualimed pharma inc.", 
"2-8437748_pryce pharmaceuticals inc", "otsuka pharmaceutical italy srl", 
"sanitpharma public subnet", "dr falk pharma benelux b.v.", "18-4178048_rose pharmacy inc.-cebu", 
"32-5203564_jehu-nissi pharma", "laboratorio drag pharma", "ntt data for egis pharmaceuticals plc", 
"sasakawa pharmacy", "pharmathen lan", "pharma square co. ltd.", 
"kobayashi pharmaceutical co. ltd.", "dr. kade pharmazeutische fabrik", 
"merlion pharmaceuticals pte ltd", "alphalytik pharmaservice gmbh", 
"pharmacontrol electronics gmbh", "millennium pharmaceuticals inc.", 
"oldens pharmacy inc", "bentley pharmaceuticals", "taisho pharmaceutical rd inc.", 
"meda pharmaceuticals inc-somerset- data", "contract pharmacal corp", 
"pharma smart international inc", "shanghai china pharmaceutical co. ltd.", 
"jebix corp dba mt olivet pharmacy", "changzhou 100 pharmaceutical network technology co. ltd.", 
"jingjiang shutaibao pharmacy co. ltd", "pharmaceutical product development inc", 
"banner pharmacaps inc", "salix pharmaceuticals", "pharmavail benefit management", 
"zhejiang zhejiang university life pharmacy ltd.", "pharmacy monument", 
"ann's pharmacy and discount", "fjfz-haihuapharmacy-corp", "pharmaceutical trade services", 
"frank s pharmacy adva", "cadila pharmacy", "grand river pharmacy", 
"pharmacy support services", "pharmakon solutions", "akorn pharmaceuticals", 
"cabernet pharmaceuticals", "galloway pharmacy ii", "strawberry family pharmacy inc.", 
"penitas family pharmacy", "apothecare pharmacy", "ream's pharmacy- accounting office bluffdale", 
"united pharmacists network inc", "owl specialty pharmacy", "american surgical pharmacy", 
"alkemists pharmaceuticals", "unisel pharma 122261", "j.b.chemicals pharmaceuticals ltd", 
"medical arts pharmacy", "alcon pharmaceuticals ltd. parstavnieciba latvija", 
"affinium pharmaceuticals inc", "medical pharmacies group ltd", 
"natural pharmaceuticals sp.z.o.o", "grossiste pharmaceutique", 
"laboratoire pharmaceutique de faconnage", "selarl pharmacie dagher", 
"pharmaserve alliance sdn bhd", "leo pharma ges.m.b.h.", "ppd pharmaceutical develo", 
"novartis pharma zrich interxion", "ftip003144466 pharma mix ltd", 
"the royal pharmaceutical society of gb", "pharmanet ltd - ho", 
"alpharmaxim limited", "western pharmaceutical centrum", "rbgqpo2013122756673_paramed pharmaceuticals inc.", 
"solvay pharma lan", "18-4231499_coson pharmacy", "20-83752_metro pharma", 
"2-8462367_medchoice pharma inc.", "germed pharma s p a", "smejup2013092625312_universalgenerics pharmacy inc."
)), .Names = "org_name", row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to post the example data instead of images.  Try `pat <- paste(train$name, collapse="|"); test[grep(pat, test$org_name),]`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this would return all test columns, but i want for each row of train corresponding rows of test (if possible in a row next to train$name)

Comment: I didn't test it.  It is better you post the example without the image as we have to manually type in the data with image.

Comment: sorry for the unorganized data, i tried dput but couldn't organize it

Comment: Some keywords don't have any match.  Try `Filter(function(x) nrow(x)>0,lapply(as.character(train$name), function(x) {indx <- grep(x, test$org_name);data.frame(indx, org_name=test$org_name[indx])}))`

Comment: @akrun thanks - only saw your comment after I'd posted my solution

Comment: @NickK It's okay.  You posted around the same time I commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ply` series of functions either in base R or `plyr`.

```
 lapply(train$name, grep, test$org_name)
```

Or if you want a single string for each:

```
sapply(train$name, function(x) paste(grep(x, test$org_name), collapse = ","))
```

This could be assigned to a new column of train if desired, e.g.

```
train$matched <- sapply(train$name, function(x) paste(grep(x, test$org_name), collapse = ","))
```

If you wanted the names rather than row numbers:

```
train$matched <- sapply(train$name, function(x) paste(grep(x, test$org_name, value = TRUE), collapse = ","))
```